# Tornado / MotorEngine - Return query as object

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, motorengine

When making a Query with MotorEngine

```
balance = yield Balance.objects.filter(status="enabled").find_all()
```

it returns something like:

```
<models.Balance object at 0x7f1f076bde90>
```

How I can turn it into something more manageable?

Comment: what do you mean by *turn it into something more manageable*?

Comment: @user3100115 like an object. Thus I could do: Balance.available_money